# How to center a horizontal line of divs?

Tags: html, css

I need three boxes centered and ordered horizontally. Right now I have the centered but only vertically:

[image]

Here is the CSS for the box:

```
.box {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #9FDCED;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add a fiddle and a more detailed image of your expected outcome. I'm not sure but I believe you are mixing up vertical and horizontal.

Comment: I just want those 3 boxes to be lined horizontally, rather than vertically

Answer (score 4):

Give the `.box` a `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` to make them be aligned next to eachother. If you surround it with a `.container` `<div>` that gets `text-align: center` the inline content gets horizontally centered.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: #9FDCED;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.box--high {
  height: 75px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box--high"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

A great resource for horizontal and vertical centering using CSS is https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box1 {
 display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
 background-color: #9FDCED;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
 <div class="box" style="background:#cc0000;"></div>
 <div class="box" style="background:#cceeff;"></div>
 <div class="box" style="background:#eeccff;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `float:left;` to the `.box` class. Like this

```
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #9FDCED;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

Working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wcvgs1zb/

Comment: But this solution doesn't have the boxes centered anymore. Now they all are on the left side of the screen